# I need some example of long term scheduler and short term scheduler

Tags: operating-system, computer-science, scheduler, job-scheduling

I have search some information about scheduler,and I can find many scheduler algorithm,but I fail to find which are long term schedulers,and which are short term scheduler.
For example,I know what is short job first scheduler algorithm,but I don't know it is long term scheduler or short term scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for operating system task scheduler (short term: what task gets a CPU now) vs. something like cron (run scheduled tasks long term).

Or other long-term job scheduling includes HPC cluster batch queueing systems, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_scheduler#Batch_queuing_for_HPC_clusters

Your OS task scheduler decides (on most interrupts) whether to do a context-switch or return to user-space in the current process.  So it's definitely short term, but it can also take into account long-term factors like whether a process typically uses up its whole time-slice: if not it might be an interactive task and should be given a priority boost in future any time it's ready to run.